# Calculating continuation of movement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a sprite that is controlled using the device's `accelerometer`.

My code for that is like this:

```
// for rotation
double myRadians = Math.atan2(previousRoll, previousPitch);
float myDegress = Math.round(((myRadians*180)/Math.PI));
// set rotation of sprite   
sprite.setRotation(myDegress+90);

// for movement
float yChange = Math.round(previousRoll);
float xChange = Math.round(previousPitch);
float yMove = Math.round(yChange/1.5);
float xMove = Math.round(xChange/1.5);
// set the position of the sprite
sprite.setPosition(sprite.getX()+xMove, sprite.getY()+yMove);
```

Which works just fine.

When the user presses the back key the game gets paused, and, obviously, stops the sprite from moving. But say if the sprite was just about to collide, the user would just be able to pause, then tilt the device in the opposite direction and voila! They get away!

All I have here is the speed, which is defined by the device's tilt, and I do store the tilt before the pause event is fired and use that for the movement when the game resumes.

So, how would I go about preventing the above? 
I was thinking I could move the sprite to the final position that it would have ended up if the game had not been paused.

How would I calculate the distance from the current position to the end position, given that I have the speed. I know `distance = speed * time`, so is there a way to get `time` in this context? Or is there another way of doing this? I'm not too good with Physics, as you have probably figured =]]

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the angle of the sprite at time of pause? If you have that and speed you can extrapolate.

Comment: @Nikki Yes, I do have the angle of the sprite at time of pause. How would I go about the extrapolation as I can't seem to figure out the final position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my issue, what I done was found the final position based on `distance = speed * time`. 
So, now my sprite moves to the "final position".

Thanks for the help.